# filter df based on index condition

Tags: pandas

I have a df with lots of rows:

```
13790226       0.320  0.001976    
9895d5dis    182.600  0.040450     
105066007     18.890  0.006432     
109067019     52.500  0.034011     
111845014     16.400  0.023974     
11668574e      7.180  0.070714     
113307021      4.110  0.017514      
113679I37      8.180  0.010837
```

I would like to filter this df in order to obtain the rows where the index last char is not a digit

Desired df:

```
9895d5dis    182.600  0.040450
11668574e      7.180  0.070714
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df['is_digit'] = [i[-1].isdigit() for i in df.index.values]
df[df['is_digit'] == False]
```

But I like regex better:

```
df[df.index.str.contains('[A-z]$')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the column on which you are filtering index or a column? If its a column

```
df1 = df[df[0].str.contains('[A-Za-z]')]
```

Returns

```
    0           1       2
1   9895d5dis   182.60  0.040450
5   11668574e   7.18    0.070714
7   113679I37   8.18    0.010837 #looks like read_clipboard is reading 1 in 113679137 as I
```

If its index, first do

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Great use of you own name!

Comment: @piRSquared, That's my love for regex:)

Comment: I used `'A-Za-z'` in a previous answer of mine purely for your benefit :-)

Comment: An honor I would say :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a concise way without creating a new temp column:

```
df
                b         c
a                          
9895d5dis  182.60  0.040450
105066007   18.89  0.006432
109067019   52.50  0.034011
111845014   16.40  0.023974
11668574e    7.18  0.070714
113307021    4.11  0.017514
113679I37    8.18  0.010837

df[~df.index.str[-1].str.isnumeric()]
                b         c
a                          
9895d5dis  182.60  0.040450
11668574e    7.18  0.070714
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this into the mix:

```
df.loc[[x for x in df.index if x[-1].isalpha()]]
```